# MySQL function returns different ouput than its code

Tags: mysql, sql, function, stored-procedures

I've created a function that returns a `date` object.

```
    CREATE
        FUNCTION FLOAT2DATE(
            value float
        ) RETURNS DATE RETURN str_to_date(
                cast(
                    value as char
                ),
                '%Y%m%d'
            );
```

When I run the code, everything works as expected.
But when I run the code due the function, it doesn't work as expected and it returns a wrong value.

```
    SET @VALUE = 20160101;
    select FLOAT2DATE(@VALUE) as func, null as code
    union 
    select null as func , str_to_date(
                cast(
                    @VALUE as char
                ),
                '%Y%m%d'
            ) as code;

func       |code       |
-----------|-----------|
2015-12-31 |           |
           |2016-01-01 |
```

MySQL Version

```
select @@version

@@version  |
-----------|
5.7.19-log |
```

Any Ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: declare @value as float and then check

Comment: Float data types are approximate values https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html use int instead.

Comment: I see no reason why you would want to use a float or anything with decimal points.  But if you do, use `decimal`/`numeric` so the representation is exact.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I use float because the existing datatype column is float. That's nothing I've decided.

Comment: @Markus . . . Well, you are learning why that is a bad idea.  I can think of no good reason for storing a date/time value as a float rather than using native database types -- unless the purpose is to intentionally obfuscate the system.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I completely agree

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the comments, with INT it works

```
CREATE
    FUNCTION FLOAT2DATE(
        value INT UNSIGNED
    ) RETURNS DATE RETURN str_to_date(
            cast(
                cast(
                    value as UNSIGNED
                )as char
            ),
            '%Y%m%d'
        );
```